# What is the probing depth of the XAS spectroscopy at Iron edge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spectroscopy, x-rays

I want to find the probing depth of the XAS spectroscopy at Iron edge, I found this paper: Magnetic circular dichroism study of Fe/Co/Cu (001) using electron yieldx-ray absorption spectroscopy with different probe depths but I still don't know how can I find the probing depth from this graph

[image]

Can somebody explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X-ray absorption is measured here by the total electron yield (TEY) method which is often assumed to be sufficiently limited to a surface region to be representative.

At some of these strongly absorbing "white lines" that is not the case. Corrections need to be made when the absorption is so strong that most of the x-ray attenuation is within this thin layer.

Without a reference, I find it difficult to say anything more.

Comment: Thank you very mcuh for answer but in the figure there is no white lines. I could not understand what/where are white lines?

Comment: @j.doe "White line" is a historical term from the age of photographic recording of x-ray absorption spectra. At wavelengths where absorption was very strong, the photographic plate was not blackened.

Comment: Thank you very muc for answer